# Entering Data into jGrasp without using a GUI

Tags: java, project, jgrasp

My class got a Java programming project today in class and the program we are using is jGrasp, I know that I can handle the pieces of this project except for one aspect.

The project requires the user to enter data into the program (i.e. answer a question), but for this Semester we are not using GUIs so I can't create a GUI for the user to input the data or *answer*.

I'd like to know how could the user enter data into jGrasp without using a GUI?

Thanks for taking the time to read this post, and I'd greatly appreciate any help you could give me.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm helpful :) it's funny that I want to know about the same thing in GUI & you want to know without it :D ....well i can solve your matter I believe :)

From the starting,
Example:

> **import java.util.*;**
>    public class Assignment //class name
>    {
>    **static Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);**
>      public static void main(String[]args)
>     {
>      int A, B; //Intialize variables as normal
>    **System.out.print("Enter a question you want to ask ");** //Between the double quotes " "  you type anything you want to  type :)
>    **A = stdIn.nextInt();**
>      :  //
>      : // complete your program
>    **System.out.println("Add the statement for giving the result "+B);**  // "+B" for inserting  the answer along with your result  statement
>     }
>    }

Note: In the statements,

```
  System.out.print();
  System.out.println();
```

These statement work similarly.... just the difference is statement with "print" is displayed on the same line & Statement with "println" is displayed in next line....when you will try you will understand ...just for avoiding confusion why I have written so I'm mentioning it :)

I hope this helps...tczz :)

Comment: Thank you @Karthikeyan ...I'm new here so yet exploring things ...will try code block next time surely :)